# mvc roles and permission Design guidance required

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, user-roles

For my application, I need to setup role based authorization.  i see some samples available online, but my requirement is bit different.  I have roles like Manager, Administrator, Submitter etc.  Then i have sub roles like regional manager, country manager, regional administrator, country administrator, regional submitter, country submitter etc.  so something like roles and sub roles.

my question is, when i design this in .net MVC, what should i consider the subroles as roles and define 10 different roles based on region and sub region or should i group the roles like admin, submitter & manager and then handle the sub roles separately in the code?

what is the correct design?

is there any sample that i can look at?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I've been plagued with this same situation for many apps. Although my roles have different names. Using your naming structure, I would be inclined to follow the former structure of your suggestion.

If a user is in the following roles: Manager, Country.

Your user will still be allowed in actions marked with [Authorize(Roles = "Manager, Regional")],
but would not be allowed in actions marked with [Authorize(Roles = "Regional Manager")]

I haven't been able to find a way to prohibit roles using the [Authorize] attribute (as in, if not in role, or is in role AND in role).

Another thought, if you have a controller specific to managers, you can set the [Authorize(Roles = "Manager")] attribute on the controller and on actions as [Authorize(Roles = "Regional")] or [Authorize(Roles = "Country"] as needed.

This, I think, will allow a user only if they are in both (for instance) the 'Manager' and 'Regional' roles in some actions requiring that the user be in both those roles. This way you could have a 'Manager', 'Regional', and 'Country' roles separated. Which should make it easier to assign a user to the roles as needed.